# Convert vertices stored as mesh into curve

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, camera, path, conversion

I am relatively new to Blender and I am working on sequence of 3D point that are supposed to be a trajectory for my camera.

My points are stored as vertices of a Mesh object, with no connection between them, so I have no edges or faces.
I know a camera path should be a Curve object, so I would like to convert the mesh into a curve.

However, the function "Convert" doesn't work, because I have no edges between consecutive points.

I tried using the <kbd>F</kbd> hotkey with groups of nearby points, then removed the faces to keep only the edges.

Unfortunately this method takes a long time and sometimes skips edges, connecting wrong point pairs.
Is there a way to do this conversion or generate a path for the camera for this data type?
Thank you!

[image]